# Execute PowerShell Script from Grunt

Tags: powershell, gruntjs

I have a PowerShell script (myScript.ps1) that I need to run as part of my build process. I'm using Grunt to build my code. I cannot figure out how to run this script from Grunt. Does anyone know how to run a PowerShell script from Grunt such that the next task won't run until the PowerShell script has completed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could give a try to [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell)

Install

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-shell
```

Load

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
```

Configure

```
grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
        ps: {
            options: {
                stdout: true
            },
            command: 'powershell myScript.ps1'
        }
    }
});
```

Use

```
grunt shell:ps
```

Comment: In my case "ps" is a Powershell Cmdlet for Get-Process command. Invoking the script with "powershell" command did the job.